# Update image in page after navigation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have an image in a page:

```
<Page x:Class="pageShowImage"
    ...>

    ...

    <Image Name="imgMain" 
        Source="{Binding Image, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </Image>

    ...

</Page>
```

Which I bind to a class in the code behind:

```
Class pageShowImage

    Private DisplayedProperties As clsDisplayedProperties

    Private Class clsDisplayedProperties
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Private _Image As BitmapImage

        Public Property Image As BitmapImage
            Get
                Return _Image
            End Get
            Set(value As BitmapImage)
                value.Freeze()
                _Image = value
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Image"))
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub PageLoad() Handles Me.Loaded
        DisplayedProperties = New clsDisplayedProperties
        imgMain.DataContext = DisplayedProperties
    End Sub

End Class
```

The image is generated by some C++ code that is run in a background worker. I use some of my own code to turn this to a BitmapImage which is used to update the image property:

```
DisplayedProperties.Image = BitmapConversion.Convert2BitmapImage(img)
```

Then, in my main form I create an instance of this page when the form is loaded:

```
ShowImagePage = New Uri("Pages/pageShowImage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
```

At the right moment I then navigate to the page:

```
frameMain.Navigate(ShowImagePage)
```

And, at this stage, everything works wonderfully. When the user interacts with things, the image updates as expected.

The user then navigates away from the page, but if they then return to the page the image refuses to show. While I can see other controls in the page, the image is blank. Stepping through the code, a genuine image is passed in, and the imagebox says it is visible.

What might be causing this? I have tried to simplify the code - feel free to ask if I have omitted something important.

Comment: Where is the Image property set? As a note, you should be using the base class ImageSource as property type, not BitmapImage. Also setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on Source Binding is pointless. UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: It is also unclear why at all you have this private nested class and the Binding. If the Page's code behind has a reference to the Image element (via imgMain), you could always directly set `imgMain.Source`.

Comment: Hi Clemens, I updated the question to describe how I set the image. In brief, a background worker calls some C++ code that generates the image. I then convert this to a BitmapImage and set the class property with that.

Comment: I can remove the UpdateSourceTrigger.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in PageLoad to see if it is called when you navigate back to the Page. There you are assigning a new clsDisplayedProperties instance to DisplayedProperties. Maybe your code behind still operates on the old instance.

Comment: Yes, PageLoad() is called each time I navigate back to the page. But DisplayedProperties is nothing each time I navigate back to the page, so it feels like I should create a new instance? I previously tried a) only setting DisplayedProperties to a new instance if it is nothing; b) Setting DisplayedProperties in New() c) Creating a new instance of the page each time I navigate to it d) Not creating a new instance of the page each time I navigate to it.

Comment: A new Page is created when you navigate back. You should keep a Page's state in a view model outside the Page instance.